# Marginal Distributions from Joint Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Here's a seemingly common proof for the formula of a marginal distribution using a bivariate joint distribution, for which I'm not clear on each step:

**Setup**: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $X, Y$ be jointly continuous random variables.  Then for any Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
P((X,Y) \in B) = \int_B f_{X,Y} \, d\lambda^2,
$$
where $\lambda^2$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f_{X,Y} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is the joint probability density of $(X,Y)$.

**Claim**: (Consider $X$): $X$ is continuous with probability density function
$$
f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, d\lambda(y) \qquad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

**(Typical) Proof**: Consider $X$ and let $A$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$.  Then
\begin{align}
P(X \in A) & = P(X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R}) &\qquad (1)\\
& = P((X,Y) \in A \times \mathbb{R}) &\qquad (2) \\
& = \int_{A \times \mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) d\lambda^2 &\qquad (3) \\
& = \int_A \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) d\lambda(y) d\lambda(x) &\qquad (4) \\
& = \int_A f_X(x) d\lambda(x). &\qquad (5)
\end{align}

**My attempt at explaining each line**:

(1) The events $\{X \in A\}$ and $\{Y \in \mathbb{R}\}$ are independent and $P(Y \in \mathbb{R}) = 1$, so $P(X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R}) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in \mathbb{R}) = P(X \in A).$

(2) Definition of joint probability distribution measure

(3) Definition of joint probability density

(4) Tonelli's theorem

(5) Not sure here.  Somehow $f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, \mathrm{d} \lambda(y)$.  Certainly this is a function of $x$, but why must it be the probability density of $X$?

Do these seem correct?

---

**Update**:  Based on the helpful comments and response below, I believe the following is a valid explanation:

(1) $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A\} = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A, Y(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}\}$, so the probability of these sets are equal.

(2) Definition of joint probability distribution measure

(3) Definition of joint probability density

(4) Tonelli's theorem

(5) One goal is to show $P(X \in A) = \int_A g(x) d\lambda(x)$ for *some* $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  Certainaly $g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y} d\lambda(y) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and since densities are a.s. unique, $g$ is indeed the density of $X$; i.e. $f_X = g$.

Finally, by the definition of a continuous random variable, $X$ is continuous.

Comment: (1) independence is irrelevant here. You have a sample space $\Omega$ with two random variables $X, Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; $P(X \in A) = P(X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R})$ follows strictly from equality of events (sets). (2) That's right. (3) That's right. (4) Either $F$ or $T$ apply. (5) $g$ is a density for $X$ if and only if it is the (a.s. - unique) Radon-Nikodym  derivative $d(P\circ X^{-1})/d\lambda^2$, iff $\int_A g d\lambda^2 = \int_A d(P\circ X^{-1})$. Your $f(x)$ satisfies this, so it's the right function of $x$.

Comment: @snarski Thanks, but I thought $g$ is a density for $X$ iff $g = d(P \circ X^{-1})/d\lambda$, iff $\int_A g d\lambda = \int_A d(P \circ X^{-1})$.  Why are we allowed to define a density w.r.t the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $X \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. The square is a typo (obviously, since $\int_A g(x) d\lambda^2(x,y) = \infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof**: Consider $X$ and let $A \in \mathcal{B}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.  Then
\begin{align}
P(X \in A) & = P(X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R}) &\qquad (1)\\
& = P(\mathbf{X} \in A \times \mathbb{R}) &\qquad (2) \\
& = \int_{A \times \mathbb{R}} f(x,y) d\lambda^2 &\qquad (3) \\
& = \int_A \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) d\lambda(y) d\lambda(x) &\qquad (4) \\
& = \int_A f(x) d\lambda(x). &\qquad (5)
\end{align}

**explaining each line**:

(1)$\{\omega \in \Omega |X(\omega) \in A\} =\{\omega \in \Omega |X(\omega) \in A, Y(\omega \in \mathbb{R})\} $ $ \Bbb{P}(X \in A) = \Bbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega |X(\omega) \in A\}) =\Bbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega |X(\omega) \in A, Y(\omega \in \mathbb{R})\}) = \Bbb{P}(X\in A, Y \in \Bbb{R})  .$

(2) Definition of joint probability distribution measure

(3) Definition of joint probability density

(4) Tonelli's theorem

(5)Use the definition of $f(x) = \int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x,y) \, d\lambda(y)$

Now conclude that if $P(X \in A) = \int_A f(x) \, d\lambda(x)$ then $f(x)$ is the density of $X$

that $f(x)$ is a probability density follows from the definition of a probability density, any measurable function with the following property
$P(X \in A) = \int_A f(x) \, d\lambda(x)$

check it out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition

Comment: Thanks, your line (1) really helped.  For (5), it's not clear to me why this $f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) d\lambda(y)$...as I understand it, this is what we're trying to show - it's not a definition.

Comment: Yes, so for one moment call $g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \, d\lambda$. Note (by Fubini's theorem) that $g(\cdot)$ is measurable. In this case you will conclude that $P(X \in A) = \int_A g(x) \, d \lambda$. Use this fact to conclude that $g$ is in fact the density of $X$. Now you are free to call $g(x)$ as $f_i(x)$